# Players.Jackwithgamingyt.Playergui.ScreenGui.LocalScript:93 attempt to index with 'Name'

Tags: lua, roblox

So im trying to Use Plr.name But it did `Players.Jackwithgamingyt.Playergui.ScreenGui.LocalScript:93 attempt to index with 'Name'`

So Can any Body Help?

```
local Frame = script.Parent.Frame
local Text = script.Parent.Frame.TextLabel
Text.Text = "Lets Start" .. plr.Name .." "
```

Is There something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code sample you've provided, it looks like `plr` isn't defined. Since you are using a LocalScript, you can get access to the current player using the [LocalPlayer property of the Players service](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/Players/LocalPlayer).

```
local Text = script.Parent.Frame.TextLabel
local plr = game.Players.LocalPlayer
Text.Text = "Lets Start" .. plr.Name .." "
```